# Code coverage with Mocha

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, code-coverage, mocha.js

I am using Mocha for testing my NodeJS application. I am not able to figure out how to use its code coverage feature. I tried googling it but did not find any proper tutorial. Please help.

Answer (score 516, accepted):

You need an additional library for code coverage, and you are going to be blown away by how powerful and easy [istanbul](https://istanbul.js.org) is. Try the following, after you get your mocha tests to pass:

```
npm install nyc
```

Now, simply place the command nyc in front of your existing test command, for example:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "test": "nyc mocha"
  }
}
```

Comment: And if you're running a locally installed version of mocha, try `istanbul cover node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha`.

Comment: Or, install both istanbul and mocha locally, and add the following to the scripts section of your package.json and then just npm run coverage: "coverage": "./node_modules/istanbul/lib/cli.js cover ./node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha -- --ui bdd -R spec -t 5000

Comment: has anyone tried this using grunt and coffeescript? I've looked into grunt-mochacov which works fine in linux but not windows (and its using blanket which didnt seem overly functional to me)

Comment: https://github.com/daniellmb/grunt-istanbul-coverage or https://github.com/taichi/grunt-istanbul should work for you. And here is Coffeescript and Istanbul: https://github.com/Constellation/ibrik

Comment: I had trouble getting this command to run on windows, but by specifying the full path to the mocha bin I was able to get it to work.

`istanbul.cmd cover C:\Users\{UserName}\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mocha\bin\_mocha`

Comment: @JasonJarrett I highly recommend installing Git Bash (most easily gotten via Github for WIndows). You'll find that most commands run correctly.

Comment: `$(npm bin)` is a canonical shortcut to `./node_modules/.bin/`, and `istanbul/lib/cli.js` is aliased to `istanbul` in the bin folder. So here's a shorter command: `$(npm bin)/istanbul cover $(npm bin)/_mocha -- --ui bdd -R spec -t 5000`

Comment: @ Windows users: `istanbul cover node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha -- -R spec`

Comment: One more minor note to make this idiot proof might be the use of "--recursive"

Comment: Please note that istanbul actually parses the AST, and therefor if you have comments in your code for various things these will be removed. I spent about 2 hours troubleshooting istanbul only to have to ultimately back out and find a new solution.

Comment: You can also use https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-istanbul. It has option to specify https://www.npmjs.com/package/isparta as an instrumenter which provides code coverage for ES6.

Comment: Please note that "coverage":"istanbul cover _mocha" in package.json will not work, as it will refer to ./node_modules/.bin/_mocha instead of ./node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha where first is a shell script and the later is a js

Comment: It gives me this error: `$ istanbul cover _mocha -- -R spec
No coverage information was collected, exit without writing coverage information
C:\Users\Ulysses\AppData\Roaming\npm\_mocha.CMD:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { @IF EXIST "%~dp0
                                                              ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
`
How can I solve this please?

Comment: @UlyssesAlves Looks like you are running a windows OS, like @Pier-Luc Gendreau mentioned you will need specify 

```istanbul cover node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha -- -R spec```

Source: https://github.com/gotwarlost/istanbul/issues/90

istanbul assumes that the _mocha you specify translates to a JS file which is true in non-windows environments. In a windows environment, this is likely a batch file that is getting loaded by node and, of course, fails.

Answer (score 248):

Now (**2024**) the preferred way to use [istanbul](https://istanbul.js.org) is via its *"state of the art command line interface"* [nyc](https://github.com/istanbuljs/nyc).

## Setup

First, install it in your project with

```
npm i nyc --save-dev
```

Then, if you have a npm based project, just change the test script inside the `scripts` object of your [package.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json) file to execute code coverage of your [mocha](https://mochajs.org/) tests:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "test": "nyc --reporter=text mocha"
  }
}
```

## Run

Now run your tests

```
npm test
```

and you will see a table like this in your console, just after your tests output:

[image: Istanbul Nyc Mocha code coverage]

## Customization

#### Html report

Just use

```
nyc --reporter=html
```

instead of `text`. Now it will produce a report inside `./coverage/index.html`.

#### Report formats

Istanbul supports a wide range of report formats. Just look at its [reports library](https://github.com/istanbuljs/istanbuljs/tree/master/packages/istanbul-reports/lib) to find the most useful for you.
Just add a `--reporter=REPORTER_NAME` option for each format you want.
For example, with

```
nyc --reporter=html --reporter=text
```

you will have both the console and the html report.

#### Don't run coverage with npm test

Just add another script in your `package.json` and leave the `test` script with only your test runner (e.g. mocha):

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha",
    "test-with-coverage": "nyc --reporter=text mocha"
  }
}
```

Now run this custom script

```
npm run test-with-coverage
```

to run tests with code coverage.

#### Force test failing if code coverage is low

Fail if the total code coverage is below 90%:

```
nyc --check-coverage --lines 90
```

Fail if the code coverage of at least one file is below 90%:

```
nyc --check-coverage --lines 90 --per-file
```

Comment: This works perfectly for jasmine also :  "nyc --reporter=html jasmine"

Comment: mine works but I do not see the code coverage showing which lines are covered by green / red in the code itself.

Comment: thanks for adding "now(2017)" - really helpful in this fast moving javascript world

Comment: In case anyone else was confused - the npm repository [istanbul](https://www.npmjs.com/package/istanbul) seems to have been superceded by [nyc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nyc).  Per its listed dependencies, istanbul was split apart into various packages which are all maintained in their [istanbuljs monorepo](https://github.com/istanbuljs/istanbuljs)

Comment: I am having the `--reporter=html` enabled but the html file is empty always, there is nothing shown about uncovered blocks or % covered etc just headers of the table

Comment: `npm run test-with-coverage` fails with `(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import _ from 'lodash'^^^^^^`.

Comment: Nice this is a useful response, @lifeisfoo; It seems to be more up-to-date than this medium article: https://medium.com/the-node-js-collection/rethinking-javascript-test-coverage-5726fb272949

Does anyone have any thoughts on c8 vs istanbul? Just based on ease-of-use I'm leaning towards istanbul.

Comment: Make sure to put `--reporter` or other params of `nyc` right after `nyc` and not after `mocha` or whatever else you're using.

Comment: If your test get stuck after tests completion and don't show the coverage report. Add `--exit` parameter at the end. `test-cover": "nyc mocha --exit"`

Comment: Note: This doens't work with ESM modules.  C8 seem to be the new best option.

Answer (score 21):

The accepted answer (nyc) does not work if you are using ESM modules.

[C8](https://github.com/bcoe/c8) appears to be the best solution now, which leverages built-in NodeJS capabilities and utilizes istanbul (like nyc, and shares the same config files).

```
npm install -g c8
c8 mocha
```

It will use .nycrc for configuration.  A sample configuration I'm using is:

```
{
    "all": true,
    "exclude": ["test"],
    "output": "reports",
    "reporter" : [
        "html",
        "text"
    ]
}
```

(Note: I was pointed to c8 by an answer to another question https://stackoverflow.com/a/69846825/1949430)

Comment: It worked really well for me, even with lots of added mocha parameters, e.g. from my package.json: 
   {
    "scripts": {
      "test": "mocha --reporter=spec --recursive test/spec",
      "coverage": "c8 mocha --reporter=html --recursive test/spec",
      ...
    ...
  ...

Answer (score 20):

Blanket.js works perfect too.

`npm install --save-dev blanket`

in front of your test/tests.js

```
require('blanket')({
    pattern: function (filename) {
        return !/node_modules/.test(filename);
    }
});
```

run `mocha -R html-cov > coverage.html`

Comment: require('blanket')({
    pattern: function (filename) {
        return !/node_modules/.test(filename);
    }
});

Comment: As of 2015, blanket.js is not maintained anymore and doesn't support ES6. Istanbul is highly recommended.