# Mocha and JSCover

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, jscoverage

I am using mocha test my nodejs code. I would like to get a coverage report. I found the [JSCover](http://tntim96.github.io/JSCover/) I am trying to run. But I am getting

```
ReferenceError: _$jscoverage is not defined
```

I am executing:

```
   java -jar ../tools/jscover/JSCover-all.jar --no-instrument=node_modules -fs api/ api-coverage

test:
    @NODE_ENV=test ./node_modules/.bin/mocha \
        --require expect.js \
        --reporter $(REPORTER) \
        --timeout 2000 \
        --growl \
        $(TESTS)
    COVERAGE_ENABLED=1 $(MAKE) test REPORTER=html-file-cov
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't help you with JSCover, but I highly recommend using the fully-Javascript-based istanbul instead. Details here: [Code coverage with Mocha](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16633246/code-coverage-with-mocha/16634823#16634823)

Answer (score 1):

JSCover uses a global variable called `_$jscoverage`. Normally a specific mode of JSCover pre-defines it at the global scope (usually the browser). When you run it with mocha - the latter doesn't defines this variable, thus you have to do that by yourself - for example, the first line of the file "expect.js" you mention in the question may be:

```
global._$jscoverage = {};
```