# Karma mocha and jscoverage

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, mocha.js, karma-runner, jscoverage

We have an application written in coffee-script with node.js and are struggling to set up code coverage tools.

At the moment we have code-coverage up and running for the serverside with

- coffeeCoverage
- jscoverage
- mocha

The front end unit tests are functions with the karma test runner and mocha, and working well. But I just can't seem to find a way to get the same kind of output from karma.

Here is the command being used for the serverside:

```
mocha --compilers coffee:coffee-script --require chai --reporter html-cov --recursive test/mocha > coverage.html
```

it would seem that because the front end is also in mocha and coffee-script we should be able to do the same thing there. But karma does not support the `html-cov` reporter, and that has left me at somewhat of a dead end.

The ideal path is that karma would run like normal in phantomjs and use the mocha `html-cov` reporter to output an html file. Does anyone know were to go from here?

[Here](https://gist.github.com/Fresheyeball/6084675) is a portion of my Cake task for the serverside just for reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

karma-coverage plugin uses Istanbul to instrument the source files and generate the coverage reports.

There's a pending issue to enable the same for coffee script too https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/issues/622

Comment: Interesting. I will test this soon.

Comment: I guess I will just have to wait on the merge.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend switching from jscoverage to istanbul to calculate your code coverage. istanbul supports mocha (be sure to call _mocha) and is the default code coverage tool for karma. Details here: [Code coverage with Mocha](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16633246/code-coverage-with-mocha)

Comment: The only problem I have there is that the istanbul mocha pattern does not appear to offer coffee-script support. Ideally I would like coverage reports to correspond to true source code and not rendered source.

Comment: Understandable. Did you try this? https://github.com/gotwarlost/istanbul/issues/43

Comment: I did look at that. However karma does not seem to support that flavor of istanbul.