# Karate tests run successfully but code coverage shows zero

Tags: karate, maven-surefire-plugin, jacoco-maven-plugin

Hi I have a problem the code coverage shows 0% but tests run successfully and jacoco shows 0 code coverage for the successfully run tests.

I followed the configuration shared in this link for jacoco but still it did not help.

https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-demo#code-coverage-using-jacoco

The issue is our application is packaged as a war and deployed on external tomcat. It is a spring boot app which is a multi-module maven project.

When the war is deployed on tomcat and I bring the tomcat up. Karate test case is run only when the application is up and running. The test cases run successfully but coverage shows 0. I dont see any problem with maven surefire plugin and jacoco config. Both reports are generated with 0 code coverage.

Any help is much appreciated. I cannot share the code unfortunately.

Comment: external tomcat ? no way that's going to work. getting code coverage to work even locally is a challenge. also read this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59977566/143475

Comment: Yes. I am using external tomcat when testing locally. Even when it will be deployed in production it will be a external server. @PeterThomas

Comment: nothing to add from my side. all the best 

Comment: If I try and use embedded tomcat to run Spring boot app it should work right? I am gonna try that using your example github setup as reference

Comment: it all depends :)

Comment: Hey Peter I thought you would be happy to hear this. Using embedded tomcat solved the issue. Coverage is working. Thank you so much for all your help