# No coverage nyc mocha

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, istanbul

I am just unable to figure out why test coverage is 0 even though test case is passing. I have a script in package.json:

```
"nyctest": "node --max_old_space_size=4096 node_modules/nyc/bin/nyc.js --reporter=text mocha"
```

When I run `npm run nyctest`

My test pass, but coverage is 0 percent.

[image]

Following is the test and the file is it testing:

**test.js**

```
var chai = require('chai');
var sinon = require('sinon');
var sinonChai = require('sinon-chai');
chai.should();
chai.use(sinonChai);
var application = require('../../../src/main/resources/static/js/components/app.js');

describe('sample return testing', function(){
    it('should return true', function(){
        application.sample.returnValue().should.equal(true);
    })
});
```

**app.js**

```
const sample = {
    returnValue: function () {
        return true;
    }
};

module.exports = {sample};
```

Appreciate any help.

Comment: [Use the `--all` flag to include files that have not been required in your tests](https://github.com/istanbuljs/nyc#use-the---all-flag-to-include-files-that-have-not-been-required-in-your-tests)

Comment: it didn't work..

Answer (score 13):

I hit this issue when using "type": "module" (ES Modules) with TypeScript.

There is an issue with the nyc (Instanbul) loader for ESM modules.  The recommended solution is to abandon nyc and use the native coverage now built into Node 13 and above: c8.

https://github.com/bcoe/c8

Comment: I have no way to test this as nodejs days are long gone for me. I can only upvote your answer. Thanks for the help!

Comment: This is the best answer if you managing a Typescript project. Could've saved hours if I found this answer earlier.

Answer (score 9):

By August 2020: two things:

1. You need to add the `--all` parameter.
2. Preferably use the `.nycrc` file in order to not have a long command line in your `package.json` as follows:

The minimal `.nycrc` file:

```
{
  "all": true,
  "include": [
    "test/**.js"
  ],
  "exclude": []
}
```

Comment: where is this file located?

Answer (score 4):

You need to modify your `nyctest` command with `--all` flag, as follows:

```
"nyctest": "nyc --reporter=lcov --reporter=text-lcov --all -x \"./node_modules/*\" -x \"./coverage/*\" check-coverage --lines 10 --functions 90 npm run unittest"
```

So with `--all` flag, all files are fetched

Answer (score 3):

In my case, the problem was that `.nyrc` configuration contained `"instrument": false`. Removing this brought back coverage reports.

Answer (score 3):

TL;DR: Try `useSpawnWrap: true` in your nyc config.

---

The root cause of the issue is due to the way `nyc` instruments the files for coverage. It does this by watching it's child process and keeping track of what code is ran. This is why you pass `mocha` to `nyc`

You can test if this is the case by adding the `--show-process-tree` flag to `nyc`, [as described in the nyc docs](https://web.archive.org/web/20210409015501/https://istanbul.js.org/docs/advanced/process-tree/). If you see "nyc" at the bottom of the output, but nothing under it, you will know this is your issue.

Now, the note above explains how to work around this (`useSpawnWrap: true`), but what causes it? This [GitHub issue comment](https://github.com/istanbuljs/nyc/issues/1029#issuecomment-524607893) partly explains what is happening, and [this comment](https://github.com/pnpm/cmd-shim/issues/3#issuecomment-624724543) explains how `pnpm` broke this ability. In my case I am hitting this with `nvm`, though I sure it is the same root cause, something is affecting either path, or the `process.env.NODE_OPTIONS` environmental variable.

I hope this more detailed explanation helps you troubleshoot issues like this in the future.

Answer (score 1):

My case is a little different,

I have installed `mocha` globally and when `nyc` referring mocha globally it does't show anything in the coverage report.

I got result when running

`nyc node_modules/.bin/mocha`

It is a known issue  and refer here
https://github.com/istanbuljs/nyc/issues/1029#issuecomment-514174340