# Mocha - Chai Unit Terst report generation - NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai

I am doing Unit Testing using `Mocha chai` for sample `NodeJS` project. Followed by the below reference.

https://www.sitepoint.com/unit-test-javascript-mocha-chai/

And I could run the tests successfully using terminal. It is showing success/failure test status.
But, Test Report is not generated.

I used the below command in terminal to run the test

```
npm run test
```

How do I generate the report for the test.

Comment: Do you mean the test coverage report?

Comment: @VPaul: yes, its coverage report

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try nyc (https://www.npmjs.com/package/nyc). Install as a dependency along with mocha and if your tests pass, this will generate the coverage report for you like a breeze.

I personally prefer using jest (https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest) instead of mocha/chai+nyc, it comes pre-equipped with reporting feature and pretty simple to use as well but it's your choice that matters here.

You can have a look a similar question for more reading about nyc usage: [Code coverage with Mocha](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16633246/code-coverage-with-mocha)